# MSRS column group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to prepare a report like on image below

[Report1](http://imageshack.com/a/img661/7004/P2sQyx.jpg)

When I'm trying to preview a report I get three additional columns between column Reservations and first type of stock_description

[Report2](http://imageshack.com/a/img537/8914/18GXEr.jpg)

Now in T-SQL Query in select part I have got:

```
sum(units)
sum(units_required),
sum(units_avaliable)
```

I know that t-sql ignore null values. But when I change the query to:

```
sum(isnull (units,0)),
sum(isnull (units_required,0)),
sum(isnull (units_avaliable,0))
```

then I get 0 value in those additional columns instead of null value. When query returns any value them it is where it should be - in one of the stock_description.

What should I do to delete those three columns between Reservations and stock_location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your data has NULL values of `Stock_description` field. You can put additional condition in your TSQL to exclude NULL Stock Description.

```
SELECT ....
FROM ....
JOIN ....
WHERE .....
AND TableName.Stock_Description IS NOT NULL
```

But one thing you need to watch/Test is what happens if there are units under `NULL` `Stock_description`

You can also handle this in SSRS by filtering either at Tablix or datasource but doing in SQL itself is much better.